# Working with an application written in a foreign (spoken) language

Tags: vb5

I have a VB5 application written in a foreign language (Italian). It uses an Access DB which is also in Italian.

**How can I convert this to English?**

I am possibly going to port this to .NET, but before I do I need to somehow read and understand what I am doing.

Comment: I'm afraid there's only one way to do it: translate it... You can try BabelFish or similar for a rough meaning, but getting a true translation cannot be done automatically or by code. Collect all strings and send them to a translation office (or a friend).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I wouldn't spend time or money trying to actually translate the source. Just use on-line automatic translators like [google translate](http://translate.google.com) to look up snippets of Italian you don't understand. Comments and identifiers in source code are not complex literary works. It shouldn't take you long to grok the "programming Italian" subset of Italian.